# Strange behaviour of changing UI in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

I am trying to modify UI. However I did not understand in some function I cannot modify UI. For example:

```
// In this function there is nothing wrong.
void FindUser::on_btnBrowse_clicked()
{

    browseFileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Select Image"),
                                            "file:///.1/", tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)"));

    qDebug() << browseFileName;

    if(browseFileName != "")
    {
        ui->btnFindPerson->setEnabled(true);

        selectedImg = QImage(browseFileName,"JPG");

        ui->lblFindPersonImage->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(selectedImg));
        ui->lblFindPersonImage->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
        ui->lblFindPersonImage->setScaledContents(true);

    }
    else
    {
        ui->btnFindPerson->setEnabled(false);
    }
}
    // However in this function when some operation done. Ui is not changing. I am sure that userFound() is working because I can see output of qDebug() without any problem. And also I add some Qlabel, and also they are not changing too.
    void FindUser::userFound(QString imgFileName)
{


    QStringList imgName = imgFileName.split(".");

    qDebug() << imgName.at(0);

    QString resultImgFileName = "/.1/Projects/MGFaceApp/bin/db/visible/" + imgName.at(0) + ".jpg";

    QPixmap resultImgPixmap(resultImgFileName);

    qDebug() << resultImgFileName;

    ui->lblFindResultImage->setPixmap(resultImgPixmap);
    ui->lblFindResultImage->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
    ui->lblFindResultImage->setScaledContents(true);
}
```

// Here is userFound(), where it is called.

```
bool ImageProcess::imgIdentfiy(QImage img_ident)
{
    ....
....
    ....
    if(identifyMember.identify(......))
    {
        ....

        if(matchedImgName != "")
        {
            FindUser findUserMember;
            findUserMember.userFound(matchedImgName);
        }
    }

....
        qDebug() << "Identify : DONE - DONE";
    return true;
}
```

Here is also header file:

```
    namespace Ui {
class FindUser;
}

class FindUser : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit FindUser(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~FindUser();
    void userFound(QString imgFileName);

private slots:
    void on_btnBrowse_clicked();

    void on_btnFindPerson_clicked();


private:
    Ui::FindUser *ui;
    QString browseFileName;
    QImage selectedImg;
    QString resultImgFileName;

};
```

I am trying to find which option I should check, but none of my attempts solved this problem. Do you have any idea to find this ?

EDITTED : Here is my actual code.

Comment: Are you sure userFound method is actually called? (it is not a slot)

Comment: @geoalgo, yes I added qDebug() and see output from console.

Comment: @Tay2510, sorry in my code I am using ui-> but while writing here I did mistake.. Editting question.

Comment: I'm surprised to see that setting a label's text via the assignment operator works. I would have expected something like `ui->lblPersonName->setText("...");`. Which Qt version is this?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe please see editted version it is my mistake while writing here. Normaly when I typed in Qt "." it automatically convert to "->" but here I forget to write it.

Comment: @goGud Can't you just copy and paste your code instead of typing it again? Give us a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Tay2510, again I am sorry, it is again my fault. I did not copy it from my code. Just trying to write it in easy way to be clear. So Frerich is right. Editted my question. However problem is not wrong format of type.

Comment: Please see my edit I gave you real code which is not working for me ..

Comment: What calls `FindUser::userFound`? I don't see it being called anywhere.

Comment: @thuga it is called in another class. This class is also called to another class.. I also added where it is called in question. Please see edit.

Comment: Well your `FindUser findUserMember` is going out of scope when your `if` finishes. Are you sure you want to create a new instance of `FindUser` here? I'm suspecting you already have an existing instance of `FindUser` somewhere as you can see it on your screen.

Comment: @thuga , I think that you are right. Could you please kindly help me, where I should create new instance of 'FindUser' in order to call it in another classes?

Comment: Where is your existing instance created? The one that you actually show on the screen.

Comment: @thuga, Actually `finduser.cpp` has also `finduser.ui` and buttonclicked is inside `finduser.cpp`, however, if I found person in another classes I sent `filename` to `finduser` that why I create `FindUser` in another class to send `filname` to `finduser.cpp` and creating `Qpixmap` into `Qlabel`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use signals and slots to communicate between two classes.
Create a signal in your `ImageProcess` class and turn `FindUser::userFound` into a slot.

```
signals:
    void userFound(const QString &imgName);
```

```
bool ImageProcess::imgIdentfiy(QImage img_ident)
{
    ....
        if(matchedImgName != "")
        {
            emit userFound(matchedImgName);
        }
...
}
```

And connect the signals and slots somewhere where you create the instances of these classes:

```
FindUser *fUser = new FindUser(this);
ImageProcess *imgProcess = new ImageProcess(this);
connect(imgProcess, SIGNAL(userFound(QString)), fUser, SLOT(userFound(QString)));
```

I don't know how your application works, but use this as a guide.

Comment: your solutions seems true, however I could not apply it to my code. And also I am just passing filename to class and setting to QLabel in FindUser. Why I should make such SIGNAL/SLOT connection. I think it should not necessary..

Comment: @goGud Because it's simple and easy. Neither object needs to know about the other one. Why could you not apply it to your code?

Comment: I didn't understand where I should create `FindUser *fUser` and `ImageProcess *imgProcess`.. in `imageprocess.cpp` ? and also where I should write `connect(imgProcess, Sıgnal.... )` ?

Comment: @goGud I don't know where you should create them, but you should know. You have created them. They are somewhere in your code. This was just an example. That is why I stated in the end of my answer that I don't know how your application works and that you should use my answer as a guide, not just copy paste it. It's impossible for me to know about your application's design. You can provide more information, like where you initialize your `FindUser` object and `ImageProcess` object, and I will modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: As you see in my question I initialize `FindUser` in `if statement` but you said that you should not do this because it will go out `if statement finish`

Comment: @goGud No, you claimed in your question that you can see it in your display. The instance you create in the `if` statement is never shown. You create it somewhere else.

Comment: ty for your kindly effort, I solved my problem to check local variables and also I used return value, not passing value.,

Answer (score 0):

Did you check whether the image loads correctly from disk?

Maybe the path is incorrect, or the file is corrupt, ...

You should check that `resultImgPixmap` actually contains image data. Use `resultImgPixmap.isNull()` for that, it should return `false`. Also `resultImgPixmap.height()` and `resultImgPixmap.width()` should return values greater than zero.

If `lblFindResultImage` had no previous content before the call to `FindUser::userFound` and the pixmap loading has failed, you replace an empty pixmap with another empty pixmap. Obviously in this case the UI won't change.

---

Also see thuga's comment, this also very likely the source of the problem.

Comment: Yes it loads corectly. I think thuga's is right with his comment. However I could not find solution yet.